# Nothing happens when I run my main-containing class under Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, bug-reporting

If I right-click a class, which contains `main`, then select `Debug As Eclipse Application`, nothing happens. No error messages displayed, no output in console appears.

I was already meeting this bug, but forgot, what to do with it. Something related with runtime configurations from closed projects, which are hidden, but still have this malicious effect...

Answer (score 0):

Dependency project was closed. Warning was displayed, saying "Error exists in dependency project(s)", listing the project itself (not the dependency project closed, i.e. not correct cause). But this warning is often displayed, when syntax errors exist in elsewhere in the project. If tiny testing class with `main`, this warning should be ignored. This time there were no syntax error in any project source, but red exclamation mark was present at the project root node in `Project Explorer`, without any explanations. I regard this as Eclipse bug.